# Youtube videos does not loads in WebView

Tags: java, android, webview

I created a WebView for [YouTube](https://m.youtube.com) . The URL loads but the videos does not loads.

```
WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
web.loadUrl("http://youtube.com");
```

### Edited:

That problem is now fixed after setting WebChromeClient.

```
web.setWebChromeClient(new ChromeClient());
```

**Create a new class which extends WebChromeClient**

```
public class ChromeClient extends WebChromeClient{

}
```

Comment: Check your url is incorrect!

Comment: @luea099, Did you add `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` on `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Answer (score 3):

As I found that YouTube is working in default browser used. this workaround to get it working

You have to check first, try the code below

```
if (url.contains("youtube")) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
} else {
    webView.loadUrl(url);
}
```

hope, it helps

Answer (score 0):

The url needs HTTPS not HTTP in order for it to load properly.

```
https://www.youtube.com/
```